# Ubuntu and Windows broken, bored, need an other way

Tags: usb

My 500 GB Hard Drive has 2 partitions, one is for 400 GB Windows and the other one is for the 100 GB Ubuntu.

Both are broken, I got a LiveUSB and an extra 8 GB USB which I would like to install Ubuntu.

I am an average gamer, and I would like a temporary solution, until my other question gets answered.

(https://askubuntu.com/questions/692347/left-without-any-os-available-only-with-a-liveusb-i-am-not-able-to-install-une)

What do you suggest as a temporary solution?